# Unknown Sender PHP (Code inside)

Tags: php

I've created a PHP file to work with my form on my jQuery mobile site. The form works perfectly and sends the email and errors work and all. But I keep getting the email from an (unknown sender). Subject line and email information is there. (Email coming from the form to host the host email address). Thanks for any help that can be provided.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

// Here is the email to information

$email_to = "hostemail@email.com";
$email_subject = "Customer Service Form";
$email_from = "Company";

//error code

function died($error){
    echo "We are sorry, but there were errors found with the form you submitted.";
    echo "These errors appear bellow.<br/><br/>";
    echo $error. "<br/><br/>";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br/>";
    die();
    }
//validation

if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['message'])) {
    died('We are sorry but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$error_message = "";
//$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z] {2,4}$/';
//(!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
//$error_message .='The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
//  }

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z.'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp, $name)){
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not seem to be valid.<br/>';   
    }

if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br/>';
    }
if(strlen($error_message) > 0 ) {
    died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below. \n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
        }

    $email_message .= "Name:" . clean_string ($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "E-Mail:" . clean_string ($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message:" . clean_string ($message) . "\n";

    //create email headers

    $headers = 'From:' .$email_From . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To:' . $email. "\r\n" .
    'X-MAILER: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>

    <!-- Success Message Goes Here -->
    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you shortly. <br/>
    Please Click <a href="contact.html"> here </a> to go back to the contact page.
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You usually have to purchase authenticated mail from the host... costs as much as basic hosting package (usually). Otherwise, go to your email address and add host email as a contact.

Comment: @Ozzy: Any decent web host should give you access to their SMTP servers (as most web hosts also offer free email hosting). I've never encountered even shared web hosts that required you to purchase a separate service just to send transactional emails or even marketing emails (as long as they're to confirmed opt-in lists) from your web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for the `From` header is:

```
Display Name <email address>
```

For example:

```
Company <foo@company.com>
```

Right now, you're just using "Company", which is neither a valid e-mail address on its own, nor has an e-mail address at the end.

Comment: I have the company portion of it on my actual code as $email_from = "Hardy Insurance and Risk Management"; which part of my code code are you telling me to change (just starting to work with PHP integration into HTML, sorry for some questions) approx which line? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrentTroutman: Just add an e-mail address in angle brackets to the end of the name.