# php email form issue

Tags: php, forms, email

I am having trouble setting up a PHP form. Its my first try at doing this. I have got the form to submit and send to my email. But i receive 2 emails.

[image]

Is it ment to say (unknown sender) ???? surely not.

[image]

and in this image it shows you that after only one form submit. it send one blank email, and one with text. But only the message. Whats wrong?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "adamgoredesign@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);
echo "Your Message has been sent";

?>
```

---

```
      <form id="contactform" name="contact" method="post" action="#">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="enter name" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">E-mail Address<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="address@domain.com" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="subject">Subject<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="text" tabindex="3" placeholder="subject title" required>
  </div>
 <br>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="message">Message<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea" tabindex="4" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" id="submit" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606394/unknown-sender-php-code-inside

Answer (score 4):

The `From` header should be an email address or both a name and email address in the format:

```
From: John Smith <j.smith@gmail.com>
```

It should never be just a name, which is what you appear to be doing. Also remember to terminate headers with `\r\n`.

Using user input as the `From` header is not usually a good idea because it can introduce a header injection vulnerability, and it can also cause inconsistent spam filter results. For a contact form, I suggest just using a static email address of your own.